# Order of quotient group for an infinite soluble group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

I'm having a hard time understanding soluble groups.

> If $G$ is a soluble group and
> $$G>G^{(1)}>\dots>G^{(t-1)}>G^{(t)}=\{1\}$$
> is a derived series, then is it true that $G/G^{(m)}$ is finite for all $m$?

If $G$ is finite, then it is clear to me. What if $G$ is infinite?

Comment: What is your *precise* definition of a soluble group? (I am asking because there have been a few questions recently where people have been using definitions which only hold for finite groups. Also, knowing which definitions you are using will help us help you.)

Comment: The derived series terminates in the identity after a finite number of steps.

Comment: Ok, great. So have you tried taking $G$ to be your favourite infinite abelian group and seeing what happens there?

Comment: Oh, I see. The quotient is the group $G$, then is infinite, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. (So now a more interesting question is: for all $t\geq1$ does there exists a group $G$ of derived length $t$ such that $G/G^m$ is infinite for all $m$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It need not be true for infinite solvable groups.
Let $G$ be the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,n)=\langle a,t \mid tat^{-1}=a^n\rangle$. The group is $2$-step solvable, non-nilpotent for $n\ge 2$ and we have $G^{(1)}\cong \Bbb Z[\frac{1}{n}]$ and
$G\cong \langle t\rangle \rtimes \Bbb Z[\frac{1}{n}]$, so that
$$
G/G^{(1)}\cong \Bbb Z
$$
is infinite. So the derived series is
$$
G \triangleright G^{(1)}\triangleright G^{(2)}=1,
$$
and all quotients $G/G^{(i)}$ for $i=1,2$ are infinite.